# SignalR MVC3 website and WPF client

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR hub set up on IIS Express and an example website with the standard chat sample application. It works great in the browser and I can see messages displayed across different browsers at the same time. Unfortunately, I've hit a hurdle with getting something similar to work in WPF.

I've set up the chat sample just as a base. Eventually, I will need the server to push updates to all connected WPF clients. Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

**Hub:**

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.send(message);
    }
}
```

**WPF sample class:**

```
public class ChatSample
{
    public ChatSample()
    {
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:21638/");
        var proxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("Chat");
        proxy.On<string>("send", Console.WriteLine);
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();
    }
}
```

**Current implementation gives the following exception on:**

```
hubConnection.Start().Wait();

{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I was typing out the question, I found the solution. Thought I'd leave it here in case it helps anyone else. I simply needed to supply credentials on the `HubConnection`:

```
hubConnection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Comment: Thanks!! It helped me!!